# Can I execute two commands in sed when a line matches a pattern?

Tags: sed

I have a working sed command that searches for `rm a-file`, comments it and adds another line (`rm another-file`) below it:

```
sed -e '/^rm a-file/s;^;# ;'            \
    -e '/# rm a-file/a rm another file' \
    my.script
```

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to combine both edits, the commenting *and* the appending into one command so that I have to specify the matching pattern (`/^rm a-file/`) only once.

In case it matters, I am using gnu sed.

Comment: Could you check my post and let me know if it works fine for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just regroup it like this:

**SED COMMANDS:**

```
$ cat commands.sed 
/^rm a-file/{
  s@^@# @
  a rm another file
}
```

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat myscript.sh 
rm a-file
blabla
rm a-file
blabla2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ sed -f commands.sed myscript.sh                              
# rm a-file
rm another file
blabla
# rm a-file
rm another file
blabla2
```

**Explanations:**

This will look for lines that start with `rm a-file` then replace `^` by `#` (commenting the initial rm command) then it will append the line `rm another file` only if the line respects the condition `^rm a-file`  .

This can be done in a one-liner as well, as kindly suggested by Sundeep: (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline)

```
sed -e '/^rm a-file/{s@^@# @; a rm another file' -e '}'
```

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I have edited my post and it works! I went a bit too quickly sorry ;-)

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: The issue I had was that SED append command would interpret the whole string after as the text to append including the closing squared bracket `}` what was causing the unmatched `}` error ;-)

Comment: as one liner: `sed -e '/^rm a-file/{s@^@# @; a rm another file' -e '}'` ... see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline

Comment: @Sundeep: Thanks I really appreciate your feedbacks I learn a lot thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed`, this particular case can be covered with simple substitution as well

```
$ sed 's/^rm a-file.*/# &\nrm another file/' my.script
# rm a-file
rm another file
blabla
# rm a-file
rm another file
blabla2
```

- `^rm a-file.*` to match line starting with `rm a-file`, and then `.*` to capture rest of line for re-use
- `# &\nrm another file` the `&` here would have entire matched text while `\n` would add the required newline